# Memory error in the destructor when reverse a linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

I'm writing my own linked list class (for educational purposes) and here it is:

**The node**

```
#define PRINT(x) #x << " = " << x << " "

struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode *next = nullptr;
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
};
```

**The class**

```
class LinkedList{
    private:
        ListNode* _head;
        unsigned long long int _size;
    public:

        LinkedList():_head(nullptr), _size(0) {}

        LinkedList(ListNode* _h):_head(_h), _size(0) {
            ListNode *node = _head;
            while (node != nullptr) {
                _size++;
                node = node -> next;
            }
        }

       ~LinkedList() {
            while (_head != nullptr) {
                remove();
            }
        }

        void add(const int& value) {
             ListNode *node = new ListNode(value);
             node -> next = _head;
             _head = node;
             _size++;
        }

        int remove() {
             int v = _head -> val;
             ListNode *node = _head;
             _head = _head -> next;
             delete node;
             _size--;
             return v;
        }

        void print() {
             if (size() == 0) {
                 cout << "List is empty" << endl;
                 return;
             }
             ListNode *node = _head;
             while (node -> next != nullptr) {
                 cout << node -> val << " -> ";
                 node = node -> next;
             }
             cout << node -> val << endl;
        }

         unsigned long long int size() { return _size; }
         ListNode* head() { return _head; }
};
```

I've decided to solve a LeetCode problem [Reverse Linked List](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list) and here's the solution that works:

```
// Returns the head of the reversed list
ListNode* reverseList(ListNode* head) {
    ListNode* prev = nullptr;
    ListNode* current = head;
    while(current != nullptr) {
        ListNode* next_elem = current -> next;
        current -> next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = next_elem;
    }
    return prev;
}
```

The problem is the following: LeetCode doesn't want my `main()` function, so for testing purposes I obviously used my own. Here it is:

```
int main() {

    LinkedList L;
    L.add(4);
    L.add(3);
    L.add(2);
    L.add(1);

    L.print();

    LinkedList L2 (reverseList(L.head()));
    cout << PRINT(L2.size()) << endl;
    L2.print();

    return 0;
}
```

The problem with that function is that I get this **error**: `IO_FILE(3853,0x7fff75d44000) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f92284031b0: pointer being freed was not allocated`

I can't figure out at what moment I'm trying to free a pointer that was not allocated. Where am I doing it?

Comment: I see pointer members, but no copy or move constructor. Wild guess: You violated [the rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three?rq=1).

Comment: It is as @churill says, `L` and `L2` have the same nodes, both will delete the nodes in their destructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not quite as I said in my comment, but the the [rule of three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three?rq=1) is still a good read.

The problem is sligthly different: The constructor

```
LinkedList(ListNode* _h)
```

Just takes ownership of `_h`. When you initialize a `LinkedList` with this constructor like in

```
LinkedList L2 (reverseList(L.head()));
```

`head` is the same in `L1` and `L2`. When those two lists go out of scope both will try to delete the same nodes (which works only once of cause).

Comment: So am I right that I have to write a copy constructor, create a copy of the list and pass the head node of the copy to the function to avoid that error?

Comment: @alekscooper Yes, correctly. This copy constructor will have to copy each element of the linked list.

Comment: @alekscooper just copy the interface of `std::list`